# Mongoose - how to determine whether a nested object already exist in a query?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

My database stores a `User`, which has an array of `watchMovies[]` containing a nested object `movie`.

When receiving an update/put API request, containing a `watchedMovie` object, **I want to check whether the `movie` with `id = zzz` already exist in the `watchedMovie[]` array**.

The problem is, this query doesn't do it. What am I doing wrong?

```
User.find(
  { username: req.params.username, 'watchedMovies.movie.id': movie.id },
  function (err, count) { 
    if (!err) exist = true;
  }
);
```

### Full code below:

**Schema**

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, require: true },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    ...
    watchedMovies : [{ 
        movie: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie' },
        time: Date,
        watchedDuration: Number,
    }],
})
```

**JSON request body**

```
{
    "id": "10-things-i-hate-about-you", //movie id
    "time": "2012-05-29T17:57:30.169Z",
    "watchedDuration": "88"
}
```

**Mongoose query**

```
router.put('/:username/watchedMovies', function (req, res, next) {

  //find movie
  Movie.findOne({ id: req.body.id }, function (err, movie) {

    if (err) res.send(err);

    //find if user already has the movie in the watchedMovies list
    var exist = false;
    User.find(
      { username: req.params.username, 'watchedMovies.movie.id': movie.id },
      function (err, count) { 
        if (!err) exist = true;
      }
    );   

    //if movie is already in watchedList, update User with it
    if (exist) {
      //set existing watchedMovie object
      User.update(...$set...)
    } else { // push new
      User.findOneAndUpdate(...$push...) 
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is problem , this is your model

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, require: true },
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    ...
    watchedMovies : [{ 
        movie: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Movie' },
        time: Date,
        watchedDuration: Number,
    }],
})
```

but your query is

```
{ username: req.params.username, 'watchedMovies.movie.id': movie.id }
```

dont use **movie.id**

try this

```
{ username: req.params.username, 'watchedMovies.movie': movie.id }
```

Comment: Yes this works! with `movie._id` with is the reference id.